# Django saving DateTimeField in a defined Timezone

Tags: django, datetime, timezone

This has been a really puzzling issue for me, and after several days of digging around online I've been unable to find any documentation that explains how to accomplish this. Hopefully someone here can shed some light!

I am building an application for managing events around the world. I'd like to store the event start and end times in the timezone of their specific locale, so that any user (regardless of their location) can see when that event occurs in that locale's specific timezone. For example, an event occurring in the US/Pacific timezone would be displayed to the user as September 19, 2:30PM PDT

To accomplish this, I am capturing 3 fields and storing them.

**My model:**

```
from timezone_utils.fields import TimeZoneField
from timezone_utils.choices import PRETTY_COMMON_TIMEZONES_CHOICES

class Event(models.Model):
    [...]
    event_start = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    event_end = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    event_tz = TimeZoneField(choices=PRETTY_COMMON_TIMEZONES_CHOICES, default='US/Pacific')
```

**My form:**

```
from datetimewidget.widgets import DateTimeWidget

class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    dateTimeOptions = {
        'format': 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:ii P',
        'autoclose': True,
        'showMeridian' : True
        }

    event_start = forms.DateTimeField(widget=DateTimeWidget(options=dateTimeOptions, usel10n=True, bootstrap_version=3))
    event_end = forms.DateTimeField(widget=DateTimeWidget(options=dateTimeOptions, usel10n=True, bootstrap_version=3))

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ("name","description","registration_goal","registration_sla","registration_url","event_start","event_end","event_tz",)
```

**My view:**

```
class EventCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = EventForm
    template_name = "events/event_create.html"
    model = Event

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form_tz = pytz_timezone(str(form.cleaned_data['event_tz']))
        timezone.activate(form_tz)

        print("Before: {}".format(form.cleaned_data['event_start'])) # Before: 2017-09-20 18:00:41+00:00
        form.cleaned_data['event_start'] = form_tz.localize(form.cleaned_data['event_start'].replace(tzinfo=None))
        print("After: {}".format(form.cleaned_data['event_start'])) # After: 2017-09-20 18:00:41-04:00
        form.cleaned_data['event_end'] = form_tz.localize(form.cleaned_data['event_end'].replace(tzinfo=None))

        event = Event.objects.create(
            name = form.cleaned_data['name'],
            [...]
            event_start = form.cleaned_data['event_start'],
            event_end = form.cleaned_data['event_end'],
            event_tz = form.cleaned_data['event_tz'],
        )

        print(event.event_start) # 2017-09-20 18:00:41-04:00

        messages.success(self.request, "<strong>Success!</strong> Added new event {}".format(form.cleaned_data['name']))
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**My template:**

```
<p>
  <strong>Event Start:</strong>
  <span>{{ object.event_start | timezone:object.event_tz | date:'N j Y - g:i A e'}}</span>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Event End:</strong>
  <span>{{ object.event_end | timezone:object.event_tz | date:'N j Y - g:i A e'}}</span>
</p>
```

It seems to capture that Timezone correctly, but the time displayed is not the same as the time that shows up when I print() the time in the console. Puzzler!

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Some additional detail / example on the inputs / outputs that are giving me trouble.

On /events/create form, I enter:

- Event Start: 2017-09-21 12:00:19
- Event End: 2017-09-21 13:00:19
- Event TZ: (GMT-07:00) US/Pacific

(See below:)
[image: Create Event form]

After submission, I see my dates returned as:

- Event Start: Sept. 21 2017 - 5:00 AM PDT
- Event End: Sept. 21 2017 - 6:00 AM PDT

(See below:)
[image: Event view after creation]

**EDIT 2:**

Here is the data pulled from the shell. It appears the dates are getting saved in UTC time, ignoring the timezone field.

[image: Django shell event_start / event_end dates]

Comment: Could you make your example more precise? What is the value you enter in the form, what is the command and output on the command line, and what is the output in the view.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry -- Yes, I will add this detail.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry -- just added some additional detail. Let me know if this is helpful, or if there is anything else I can add.

Comment: This looks like what you would get if `USE_TZ = False`. Can you confirm that `USE_TZ = True`? Also, what do you get when you look at the value from the console? (That is, start a shell, get an object, and look at `object.event_start`.)

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry -- thanks for the response. I have shared the shell output. It looks like the datetime objects are being saved directly in UTC, ignoring the value of the event_tz.

Comment: That's to be expected, since Django always saves datetimes in UTC. The question is why the datetime isn't being converted properly (assuming that `print(event.event_start)` in your view shows the correct value). You can try explicitly doing the conversion yourself in the view before saving (i.e. `django.utils.timezone.localtime(event_start, timezone="UTC")`), but that shouldn't be necessary if `USE_TZ = True`. In any case, your code looks correct to me, so I think there must be something wrong with your setup.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry -- thanks. To make things even more odd, I have a similar setup in the Admin form, and that works correctly.